# How do I group output when doing Non-recursive GNU make with -j option

Tags: gnu-make

We have create and are using a custom non-recursive GNU make based build system.

As such it is very fast (intended), however the standard output gets jumbled when building all dependencies using the -j option. We have tried using the --output-sync option to try and serialize the output however it is still not working exactly as desired.

Example:

```
all: foo foo2
foo: bar bar2 bar3
    @echo foo
bar:
    @echo bar
bar2:
    @echo bar2
bar3:
    @echo bar3

foo2: bar4 bar5 bar6
    @echo foo2
bar4:
    @echo bar4
bar5:
    @echo bar5
bar6:
    @echo bar6
```

When I run without -j I get the sequential output:

> make

```
bar
bar2
bar3
foo
bar4
bar5
bar6
foo2
```

When I run with -j I get:

> make -j

```
bar
bar2
bar4
bar6
bar3
bar5
foo
foo2
```

Attempting to fix the issue we tried using output-sync in make 4.0

> make -j -Otarget

```
bar
bar2
bar5
bar3
bar6
bar4
foo
foo2
```

**Is there any way to force make to group the recipes so even when we use -j option the output is:**

```
bar
bar2
bar3
foo
bar4
bar5
bar6
foo2
```

UPDATE: By the way the output when using -j is indeed random each time we run make, the examples are just the output of one specific run.

Comment: You're telling make to execute recipes in parallel; that means that the execution order of recipes will be somewhat randomized, as long as prerequisites are updated before the targets which depend on them. If you insisted that recipes be executed in serial order, you'd be defeating the point of a parallel build. I suppose you could use `make -n` to work out the canonical build order, and then reorder the output blocks according to this order, but it seems like a lot of work. As far as I know, make does not have any option which does that for you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking for, but if you want the output of GNU make when run with `-j` to be guaranteed to be exactly the same as when run without it, that's not possible.  Output sync ensures that two different jobs won't mix their output together (in your example that can't happen anyway because each job prints only one line) but it doesn't make any statement about the order in which those jobs' output is generated.

Comment: Based on the Makefile there is a a grouping ( foo, bar,bar2, ba3) and (foo2, bar4, bar5, bar6). What I am hoping to do is to preserve that grouping when it comes to the output. This is just a simple example. The actual system we have has 1000 of items to build. When the grouping is not preserved it is extremely difficult to decipher what went wrong.

Comment: I understand that the nature of using the -j flag makes it hard to do what I want. I was hoping someone out there has had the same problem and solved it somehow. What gave me hope also is that in make 4.0 they added the --output-sync option, but it does not seem to be capable of synchronizing as much as I would like it to.

Comment: As I said, output sync is very different.  It operates only on a particular recipe, ensuring that the output for that recipe is generated all together.  What you are asking for is some sort of higher-level collection between different targets so that they appear together, which is a very different thing.  I could imagine ways to do it, but they would be complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MadScientist commented it is not possible to do what I was hoping to do.